# Retry promise with delay until resolved in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, delay

I have a `connect()` function which returns a promise (it is actually a method in a class - not shown). I want this function to retry with a delay if the connection is not established (i.e. when an error occurs in the connection attempt), but so far I could not make it work.

I tried using the async js library and promise-retry library to no avail - the documentation is hard to understand. For clarity, `socket.connect` emits a 'connect' event if a connection is established.

This is my code:

```
this.socket = new net.Socket();
this.client = new Modbus.client.TCP(this.socket, this.unitID);
const net = require('net');
const Modbus = require('jsmodbus');

connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socket.connect(options);
        this.socket.on('connect', () => {
            logger.info('*****CONNECTION MADE*****');
            //does something once connection made
            resolve();
        });
        this.socket.on('error', (error) => {
            logger.error('failed to connect');
            this.disconnect();
            reject();
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it by making the function that does a single connection attempt (basically, renaming your `connect` to `tryConnect` or similar, perhaps even as a private method if you're using a new enough version of Node.js), and then having a function that calls it with the repeat and delay, something like this (see comments):

Utility function:

```
function delay(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value);
}
```

The new `connect`:

```
async connect() {
    for (let attempt = 0; attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS; ++attempt) {
        if (attempt > 0) {
            // Last attempt failed, wait a moment
            await delay(RETRY_DELAY_IN_MS);
        }
        try {
            await tryConnect();
            return; // It worked
        } catch {
        }
    }
    // Out of retries
    throw new Error("Couldn't create connection");
}
```

*(If you're using a slightly older Node.js, you may need to add `(e)` after the `catch` above. Leaving it off when you don't need it is a relatively new feature.)*

---

Re your current implementation of what I'm calling `tryConnect`, here are a few notes as comments for how I'd change it:

```
tryConnect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Keep these local for now
        const socket = new net.Socket();
        const client = new Modbus.client.TCP(socket, this.unitID);

        // Add handlers before calling `connect
        socket.on('connect', () => {

            logger.info('*****CONNECTION MADE*****');

            // NOW save these to the instance and resolve the promise
            this.socket = socket;
            this.client = client;
            resolve();
        });

        socket.on('error', (error) => {
            logger.error('failed to connect');
            // It's not connected, so no `disconnect` call here
            reject();
        });

        socket.connect(options);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed help, I really appreciate it! I just have a question regarding the tryConnect() function. Whats the intention behind keeping the socket and client local initially?

Comment: @jojopuf - So that we only put them on the instance when they're ready to be used. If the connection fails, we don't put them on the instance.

Answer (score 3):

First define a utility function for having the delay:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then chain a `.catch` handler to the `new Promise`:

```
.catch(() => delay(1000).then(() => this.connect()));
```

Of course, you should avoid an infinite series of retries. So implement some logic to definitely give up: after a fixed number of attempts, or after a certain time has passed, ...etc.

For instance, give a parameter to `connect` how many attempts it should allow:

```
connect(attempts=3) {
```

Then the catch handler could be:

```
.catch((err) => {
     if (--attempts <= 0) throw err; // give up
     return delay(1000).then(() => this.connect(attempts));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function where connect is called,
It can be called recursively, eg

```
const outerFunction = (times = 0) => {
  if (times < 4) {
    socket
      .connect(params)
      .then(() => {
        // do good stuff
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // increment the times so that it wont run forever
        times++;
          setTimeout(() => {
            // delay for two seconds then try conecting again
          outerFunction(times);
        }, 2000);
      });
  }
};
```

This way your connect function is tried three times with a spacing of 2 seconds, i hope this solves your issue